# append current user-id to all internal permalinks

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, parameter

i am toying with [myCred](https://mycred.me/) and would like to reward logged in users for sharing content bringing in visitors. myCred offers affiliate linking by user-id, so I figure, I "only" need to achieve appending the currently logged-in user's user ID to whatever permalink wordpress renders (be they posts, pages, listings, comments, buddypress actions, etc. - wherever a permalink is issued by my site), like so

?mref=Current_User_ID

I've spent the last hours sifting thru many *similar* Q&As here + trying to adapt what I found to my scenario; alas, I'm rather unskilled at any real programming and hence had no success so far.

I figured out how to check if myCred is active, 
[`if( class_exists( 'myCRED_Core' ) )`], how to limit execution to logged in users, how to get the current user's ID [`$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();`] and that I'll probably have to do something like

```
$affiliate_url = add_query_arg('mref', $current_user_id, get_permalink());
```

but I don't know how to make it apply for all links rendered for my site.

Is there a way? Thank you for what help you can provide. Cheers - LX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `the_permalink` filter.

```
function wpse_289182_permalink($url) {
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        return add_query_arg('mref', get_current_user_id(), get_permalink());
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'wpse_289182_permalink');
```

Comment: Hello, Jean-Rémi; this already works like a charm, thank you very much. 

is there a way to extend the scope of this to also encompass permalinks of comments? I have checked and so far it looks like permalinks of comments don't have the mref appended. Is that possible as well? 

Cheers :)